# Priority Queue Comparing With Custom Token in Java

Tags: java

I want to compare nodes on a graph based on cost to that node. These nodes are represented by a node class. However, I cannot edit the node class, which has no cost field. Therefore, I can't use a Comparator passed to the `PriorityQueue` to compare to nodes based on their costs. I want to be able to somehow pass the compared token as we go. For example. `priorityQueue.add(NodeA, 10)`. And then `priorityQueue.add(NodeB, 11)`. Thus, `NodeA` exits first upon a remove call because 10 < 11.

Is is possible to resolve this without creating another class containing a node and a cost field and using a comparator on that class?

Comment: "without creating another class"... why? creating another class seems like the correct solution for a logical standpoint. why don't you want to?

Comment: "Is is possible to resolve this without creating another class" No.